# console.log is omitting some key pairs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, debugging, mongoose

I'm debugging a NodeJS app where `mongodb` is being used.

When I `console.log` keys of a JS object (say `booking`) using `console.log( Object.keys(booking) )` statement, it prints:

```
[
  '$__',     'isNew',
  'errors',  '_doc',
  '$locals', '$op',
  '$init'
]
```

But When I directly print the same object using `console.log(booking)` statement, it prints:

```
{
  _id: 5eb4fef797bf1e29986e333f,
  user: 5eb413c78a84bc63f0ef83d4,
  event: {
    _id: 5eb4182c45d25b4c981a21ce,
    title: 'Test Event',
    description: 'bla bla bla',
    price: 99.99,
    date: 'Wed Jan 01 2020 05:45:00 GMT+0545',
    creator: 5eb413c78a84bc63f0ef83d4,
    __v: 0
  },
  createdAt: 2020-05-08T06:40:55.905Z,
  updatedAt: 2020-05-08T06:40:55.905Z,
  __v: 0
}
```

Now if you notice, some keys are missing both times I do `console.log`. I have no idea what the hell is going on. WHY is that happening?

I'm also using `mongoose` models. My code is like this:

```
Booking.findById({_id: args.bookingID}).populate('event').then(booking => {
    console.log( booking )
    console.log( Object.keys(booking) )
});
```

Please ask if you need anymore information.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: It probably has to do with which properties are marked as `enumerable` and which ones are not.  `Object.keys()` only lists enumerable properties, `console.log()` may list non-enumerable ones.  FYI, the behavior of `console.log()` is not controlled by any sort of uniform specification.  It varies a bit by environment.  The behavior of `Object.keys()` is governed by the ECMAScript specification.

Comment: @jfriend00 yeah it seems it has to do with enumerable properties.